# singularity background-grid not showing

Tags: sass, bundler, compass-sass, singularitygs

taken me ages to get singularity working and its been nightmare getting all my gems set up in general - i can honestly say I've hated every minute and i know i'm still not set up right - i'm just waiting for something to break.

anyway my question is how the hell do i get the background grid to show?

heres my sass fil

```
////////////////////////////////
/// SET UP SINGULARTITY GRID ///
///////////////////////////////
@include add-grid(12)
@include add-gutter(1/3)
@include add-gutter-style("split")
@include sgs-change("debug",true)
$bg-color: #fff

.container
  //@include background-grid
  margin: 0 auto
  min-height: 100% 

div
  height: 100%

body

  height: 100%
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  background: $bg-color
```

when i uncomment the background-grid it breaks and i get this in my output

```
>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
     info sass/app.sass was modified 
    error sass/app.sass (Line 172 of _background-grid.scss: Function column-count finished without @return)
identical css/app.css 
     info sass/app.sass was modified 
overwrite css/app.css 
     info sass/app.sass was modified 
    error sass/app.sass (Line 26 of _images.scss: wrong number of arguments (25 for 1..2) for `_linear-gradient')
overwrite css/app.css
```

please help so i can start developing the site i started last week!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an explanation quite a long time ago. You should be able to find it amongst the singularitygs tag. I have switched back to susy 2 because it works well and the documentation is so good. Singularitygs is very good but the documentation is not up to the mark. If you dig into the sub-directories of the singularitygs gem (whichever version), you find quite a lot of examples that will help. BTW, susy 2 and singularitygs 1.2.0 appear to be rather similar these days thanks to some collaboration last year, I believe.